# comma use for brief pause

Tags: commas

Isn't a comma needed after "aggressive" in the sentence below? If so, what would the rule be? I think it's for a brief pause, but I cannot find a solid answer on Google.

Through the years my media intake became more aggressive averaging around 10 hours a day spent just on my phone.

Comment: I'd say the comma is ***required*** (as is a pause in speech) before the optional adverbial clause ***averaging around 10 hours a day...***

Comment: I'd probably use a comma after _Through the years_ (many wouldn't, but it's optional there). However, as FF says, this parenthetical present-participial clause _needs_ a comma. As [theeditorsblog.net {participial phrases}](https://theeditorsblog.net/2011/02/06/participial-phrases-cmon-you-made-that-up/) asserts. But this is a grey area. See the duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comma before adverbial participial phrases (reduced adverbial phrases) and participial prepositions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301499/comma-before-adverbial-participial-phrases-reduced-adverbial-phrases-and-parti) (which says the issue is merely a style choice; however, some examples, as here, seem to **require** the comma).

Comment: Thanks. The duplicate solved it, but I really appreciate the info. in the blog link as well.